# Get certain digit number in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to to insert the value in sql but the value has to be 6 digit number, nothing less & nothing more than that. How should I define that?

thank you

Comment: `CONSTRAINT CHECK(column BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999)`

Comment: What version of MySQL? Older versions do not honor `CHECK` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 103928 BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999 x;
    +---+
    | x |
    +---+
    | 1 |
    +---+

    SELECT 3928 BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999 x;
    +---+
    | x |
    +---+
    | 0 |
    +---+
```

And, by way of example...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table; 

CREATE TABLE my_table(i INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT 3023 FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE 3023 BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT 102890 FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE 102890 BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+--------+
| i      |
+--------+
| 102890 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you have a number to insert, and you want to ensure it's a six digit number.  That is, you want `1234` to look like `001234` and `1234567` to look like `234567`.

In MySQL, you can use `RIGHT(LPAD(@item_to_insert, 6, 0),6)`   ...

```
INSERT INTO tbl (...,six_digit_column,...) 
       VALUES( ..., RIGHT(LPAD(@item_to_insert, 6, 0),6), ...);
```

Comment: Don't you miss the length parameter for RIGHT()?